# Save a text file to a remote file server using python production code

Tags: python-3.x, file, remote-server

I have to save a text file to a remote file server instead of my local system. I am using python3. Initially, I have looked up this and found `subprocess` method to do it. However, I want to know from the experts which is the best way to do the same(saving a text file in a remote file server) in production.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the scp bash command (it copies files over SSH) with subprocess.run:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["scp", FILE, "USER@SERVER:PATH"])
```

Or try the Python [Paramiko](https://www.paramiko.org/). It's very easy to use:

```
import os
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient() 
ssh.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".ssh", "known_hosts")))
ssh.connect(server, username=username, password=password)
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.put(localpath, remotepath)
sftp.close()
ssh.close()
```